# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'addEventListener' on 'EventTarget': The callback provided as parameter 2 is not an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

On the ["Go Make Great Things" blog](https://gomakethings.com/a-vanilla-javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-on-method/) by ChrisFerdinandi there is a great post about creating a "Vanilla JS" version of the `.on()` method from the jQuery library.

```
var on = function (event, elem, callback, capture) {
    if (typeof (elem) === 'function') {
        capture = callback;
        callback = elem;
        elem = window;
    }
    capture = capture ? true : false;
    elem = typeof elem === 'string' ? document.querySelector(elem) : elem;
    if (!elem) return;
    elem.addEventListener(event, callback, capture);
};
```

Am I wrong that a ternary or some conditional is needed because `addEventListener` takes a string to set the bubbling or capturing?

```
capture = capture ? true : false;
capture = capture  === true ? 'true' : 'false';
```

So I am trying to utilize the code above to create a rollover but I'm getting,

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'addEventListener' on 'EventTarget': The callback provided as parameter 2 is not an object.
```

Here is the markup:

```
     <a href = "#">
       <img class="make-up-img color-palette" alt="Eyes on you - Color Palette"
src="https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dw685f8968/images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_NO_HOVER_1.jpg?$staticlink$" />
    </a>
```

Here is the script:

```
var on = function(event, elem, callback, capture) {
  if (typeof elem === 'function') {
    capture  = callback;
    callback = elem;
    elem     = window;
  }
    console.log(capture)

  capture = capture ? true : false;
  capture = capture  === true ? 'true' : 'false';

  console.log(capture)

  elem = typeof elem === 'string' ? document.querySelector(elem) : elem;
  if (!elem) return;
  elem.addEventListener(event, callback, capture);
};



function rollOver(elem){
  if (document.querySelector(elem).getAttribute('src', 'https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dw685f8968/images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_NO_HOVER_1.jpg?$staticlink')) {
  return document.querySelector(elem).getAttribute('src', 'https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dw685f8968/images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_NO_HOVER_1.jpg?$staticlink')
  }
   return document.querySelector(elem).getAttribute('src', 'https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dw685f8968/images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_NO_HOVER_1.jpg?$staticlink');
}


on('mouseover', '.color-palette', rollOver('.color-palette'));
```

Comment: See the answers to the linked question (in that question, it's a setTimeout callback instead of an event callback, but it's the same problem). `rollOver('.color-palette')` **calls** `rollover` and passes its return value (a string) into `on`. The string isn't an object (specifically, a function), so `addEventListener` is unhappy with it.

Comment: *"Am I wrong that a ternary or some conditional is needed because addEventListener takes a string to set the bubbling or capturing?"* Yes, that's incorrect. For the third parameter, it expects `true` or `false` (a boolean value), not `"true"` or `"false` (strings). But the error relates to `callback`, not `capture`.